# Web Forms For Marketers (WFFM) Visual Fields for custom Field Type not displaying

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I've used the following code to add two properties to Form Designer but they won't display. The field type is similar to Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.CheckboxList and I need it to display the same properties. Unfortunately I can't step into this code and the module isn't throwing any errors so I feel like I'm missing something simple.

```
public class CheckBoxListPipedField : Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.Fields.CheckBoxListField
{
    [VisualCategory("List")]
    [VisualFieldType(typeof(Sitecore.Form.Core.Visual.ListField))]
    [VisualProperty("Items:", 100)]
    public ListItemCollection ListItems { get; set; }
    [VisualCategory("List")]
    [VisualFieldType(typeof(MultipleSelectedValueField))]
    [VisualProperty("Selected Value:", 200)]
    public ListItemCollection SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public CheckBoxListPipedField(Item item) : base(item)
    {

    }

    public override ControlResult GetResult()
    {
        var values = new List<string>();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
        if (this.Items != null)
        {
            foreach (SelectListItem selectListItem in
                from item in this.Items
                where item.Selected
                select item)
            {
                values.Add(selectListItem.Value);
                stringBuilder1.AppendFormat("{0}, ", selectListItem.Text);
            }
        }
        var results = string.Join("|", values);
        return new ControlResult(base.ID.ToString(), base.Title, results, stringBuilder1.ToString(0, (stringBuilder1.Length > 0 ? stringBuilder1.Length - 2 : 0)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried inheriting from `Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.CheckboxList` rather than `Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.Fields.CheckBoxListField`?.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why they wouldn't show up as the default code for the CheckboxListField doesn't have those, but try:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ListSelectItemsConverter))]
public override List<SelectListItem> Items
{
    get
    {
        return base.Items;
    }
    set
    {
        base.Items = value;
        if (this.Items != null)
        {
            this.Value = (
                from x in this.Items
                where x.Selected
                select x.Value).ToList<string>();
        }
    }
}

[ParameterName("selectedvalue")]
[PropertyBinder(typeof(ListFieldValueBinder))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ListItemsConverter))]
public override object Value
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

You might be able to just set these to `get { return base.Column }`, etc, but here is how it looks on the base class.

```
[DefaultValue(1)]
public int Columns
{
    get;
    set;
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(StringToDirection))]
public Direction Direction
{
    get;
    set;
}

public int Rows
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Items.IsNullOrEmpty<SelectListItem>())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        int num = (this.Columns == 0 ? 1 : this.Columns);
        if (this.Items.Count % num <= 0)
        {
            return this.Items.Count / num;
        }
        return this.Items.Count / num + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the code in question. I neglected to add the assembly and class to the new Field Type, and had only set the MVC type.